# Dymola Store Outputs Options Greyed Out

Tags: dymola

I'm running a batch of simulations in Dymola 2021x and in terms of outputs, I only care about some of the state variables. I figured the easiest way to limit the selection would be to go into Simulation Setup>Output>Store and leave only the "State variables" box checked. But all the options are greyed out and checked so I can't limit the outputs.

[image: Store Outputs Options]

Is there a setting in Dymola that would disable the store output options?

I've tried restarting Dymola and rebooting my PC but as kind of expected, nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the variable dependencies disable the outputs.

[image]

From the command line:

```
Advanced.GenerateVariableDependencies = true;
```

Maybe there are others as well, but that's the only one I am currently aware of.

Comment: And a bit of unnecessary clarification: The reason is that plotting the variable dependencies require that you have stored the variables. (Technically there could be a 'non-stored' indicator for the plots, but that would feel odd - especially as they might appear as intermediate variables.)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: In order to reduce the size of your results you could try the selection feature https://www.claytex.com/blog/selection-of-variables-to-be-saved-in-the-result-file/